# Solr 4.10.2 Encoding

Tags: solr

**Things to know:**

- I'm using Solr 4.10.2 locally with Tomcat 8
- My settings in Netbeans IDE are: **Encoding:** windows-1252 | **PHP:** 5.3 (need to be this way)
- I'm using xampp 1.7.7 in Windows 7 x64
- My server.xml file from Tomcat starts with `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>`
- My server.xml file from Tomcat have this URIEncoding="UTF-8" in connector tag
- My php SolrPhpClient files are coded in UTF-8 without BOM

**Situation:**

When I'm searching in my web application with Solr, if I search for the word *Diário*, the Solr Url called is:

h**p://localhost:8080/solr/select?sort=score+desc&fq=%28searchfield%3A%28di%E1rio%29+OR+isbn%3A%28di%E1rio%29%29&wt=json&json.nl=map&q=%28searchfield%3A%28di%E1rio%29+OR+isbn%3A%28di%E1rio%29+OR+titulo%3A%28di%E1rio%29+OR+autor%3A%28di%E1rio%29+OR+editoraid%3A1%5E0.00001+OR+editoraid%3A2%5E0.00001+OR+editoraid%3A133%5E0.00001+*val*%3A%22ord%28ano%29%22%29+AND+status%3A%28active%29&start=0&rows=10

**If I use urldecode() I get:**

h**p://localhost:8080/solr/select?sort=score desc&fq=(searchfield:(diário) OR isbn:(diário))&wt=json&json.nl=map&q=(searchfield:(diário) OR isbn:(diário) OR titulo:(diário) OR autor:(diário) OR editoraid:1^0.00001 OR editoraid:2^0.00001 OR editoraid:133^0.00001 *val*:"ord(ano)") AND status:(active)&start=0&rows=10

**Problem:**

The problem is, off course, with *Diário* word.

I have try insert directly on my browser this two querys:

The first one give me an error:
HTTP Status 400 - {msg=URLDecoder: Invalid character encoding detected after position 18 of query string / form data (while parsing as UTF-8),code=400}

If I use the second one it works like a charm!

I have already saw, with mb_detect_encoding() function and I'm supposedly sent all it utf-8 encoding.

Why is SolrPhpClient using something like urlencode() but then it can't decode it?

Can anyone help with this one?

Thank you in advance.

Best regards,

Marcelo

Comment: Did you try adding URIEncoding="UTF-8" to Connector definition in tomcat's server.xml

Comment: Hi, yes, I have something like <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443"      URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
Still the same error message.

Comment: It seems like a client library related problem. You may want to try Solarium: https://github.com/basdenooijer/solarium

Comment: Hi foozy, I have tried PECL solr to and the same happen, have read about Solarium but first I try the MatsLindh solution and it works.
Thanks for your time/help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, you're using windows-1252 as the encoding, and the submitted data is in windows-1252. You'll have to convert it to UTF-8 (through iconv, for example: `iconv("cp1252", "utf-8", $text)`) before querying or inserting it into Solr.

The encoding of your source files won't affect the encoding of the data in your application, and unless you're working with UTF-8 when interfacing with Solr, you're going to run into issue all over the place. Convert it to UTF-8 when submitting and querying Solr, and convert it back to cp1252 when it arrives back into your app if needed.